# BigDL: get hidden layer's output from auto-encoder model

Tags: autoencoder, dimensionality-reduction, bigdl

After training an autoencoder with one hidden layer using BigDL and Spark, I want to extract the hidden layer output with the "encoded" hidden layer of size 128. How can I do it?